# IVP in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I stuck in this question. I don't know what should I do when the question wants me to use initial value.

Solve the following IVP:

$$\left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)dx~-~x~dy~=0~,~~~~~~~~y(1)=0$$

Comment: solve it in general and then adjust the constant of integration so that your function satisfies the initial condition.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)dx~-~x~dy~=0$$
$$\implies y~dx+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~dx~-~x~dy~=0$$
$$\implies y~dx-~x~dy~+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}~dx~=0$$
$$\implies \dfrac{y~dx-~x~dy}{x^2}~+\sqrt{1+y^2/x^2}~dx~=0$$
$$\implies d\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)~+\frac 1x\sqrt{1+y^2/x^2}~dx~=0$$
integrating we have,
$$\ln\left(y/x+\sqrt{1+y^2/x^2}\right)+\ln x=\ln c$$
$$\implies \ln\left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)=\ln c$$
$$\implies y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}= c$$where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Given that $~y(1)=0~,$ so $~0+1=c\implies c=1~$ and hence the particular solution of the given differential equation is $$ y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1~.$$